# how Loading CSV file on Hive Table with Array of arrays?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
48,Snacks that Power Up Weight Loss,Aidan B. Prince,[[Health&Fitness,Travel],[dance,singing]]
99,Snacks that Power Up Weight Loss,Aidan B. Prince,[[Photo,Travel],[sport]]
```

how do you load csv with array of arrays into a hive table

<sub>The above code is a modified copy of code found in [Loading CSV file on Hive Table with String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33984794) copyright 2015 by [Deepesh Shetty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953131/deepesh-shetty)</sub>

Comment: Could you please share your code with you ? Or at least some research you have done to find an awser by yourself.

Comment: here they load a array of a dimension
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984794/loading-csv-file-on-hive-table-with-string-array




but I need to load array of two dimensions